# Android Spinner load with empty value (popup is shown before populating data)

Tags: java, android

I am using https://github.com/Chivorns/SmartMaterialSpinner Library for spinner.
When i first click the spinner no adapter is attached to it or spinner items shows empty list..
like

[image]

but when i close it and again select it.. data are shown so I believe that .. due to time consuming data fetching .. spinner show empty dialog.. Now I need to handle that.. How can i only show spinner when data is populated or available.. I have tried async task and handler but not get working.. any hint would be appreciated.. Thank you

Edited ...
I have call api on spinner onTouch event to populate data

```
 {
   private void ProvinceSpinnerCode(boolean IsEditCase) {

    if (IsEditCase) {
        //edit case condition
    } else {
        provinceSpinner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mService = RetrofitManager.getApiClient().create(RetrofitInstance.class);
                Call<List<SelectModel>> provinceCall = mService.GetProvinces();
                provinceCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<SelectModel>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<SelectModel>> call, Response<List<SelectModel>> response) {
                        if (response.body().size() >= 0) {
                            provinceSpinner.setAdapter(new SpinnerAdapter(response.body(),AddCustomerActivity.this));

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<SelectModel>> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    provinceSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(AddCustomerActivity.this, "Id is : " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            provinceId = (int) id;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: can you show how you re implementing the code , populating the spinner with data ?

Comment: @takieddine sir, I have placed my code on onCreate function. i have just attached my customer adapter to spinner..

Comment: i guess the problem is because the spinner will only be populated after ontouchlistener , other than it won't show

Comment: @takieddine Thankyou for response sir.. I m implementing cascading form where i have no. of spinner.. so i need to have some event trigger to check previous spinner has value or not.. if not then i need to show some msg.. thats why i have use onTouch Listner.. Sir Is there any other eveent i can use.. Onclick is not working... Thankyou again..

Comment: do you know how to debug apps ! debugging can help understanding what is going on with your code

Comment: yes sir.. I have done that ... But while debugging .. list is empty on first hit.. and if i trigger again there there is list from api..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217895/discussion-between-bks0088-and-taki-eddine).

Answer (score 1):

You are making an API call inside on touch event which will be fired when you will touch the spinner so to solve the problem just do Api call out side that event (may be inside Oncreate).

Right now provinceSpinner has a touch listerner so when you are touching it to open for the first time it is Fetching data so when you are clicking it again the alert is showing data (the data you fetched when you clicked first time)